# Python: how to reduce the dimension of a matrix by doing the sum of the first neighbors?

Tags: python, matrix

Suppose we have a matrix of dimension `N x M` and we want to reduce its dimension preserving the values in each by summing the firs neighbors.

Suppose the matrix `A` is a `4x4` matrix:

```
A =
  3  4  5  6
  2  3  4  5
  2  2  0  1
  5  2  2  3
```

we want to reduce it to a `2x2` matrix as following:

```
 A1 =
  12    20
  11     6
```

In particular my matrix represent the number of incident cases in an `x-y` plane. My matrix is `A=103x159`, if I plot it I get:

[image]

what I want to do is to aggregate those data to a bigger area, such as

[image]

Comment: In other words you want to replace each 2x2 submatrix by its sum?

Comment: I want to reduce the dimension of a matrix that by keeping its values.

Comment: What do mean by "keeping its values"? And the dimension (2D) stays the same. Your example steams from halving the size by summing over the 2x2 submatrix blocks, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum parts of numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582544/sum-parts-of-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using a `numpy.matrix`:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([
    [3,4,5,6],
    [2,3,4,5],
    [2,2,0,1],
    [5,2,2,3]
])
N, M = A.shape
assert N % 2 == 0
assert M % 2 == 0
A1 = np.empty((N//2, M//2))
for i in range(N//2):
    for j in range(M//2):
         A1[i,j] = A[2*i:2*i+2, 2*j:2*j+2].sum()
```

Though these loops can probably be optimized away by proper `numpy` functions.

Comment: you would need `N//2` for python 3 compat. or you'll get floats.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good point, the `assert` doesn't prevent Python3 from using float division, thanks

Comment: That works. However In my case I have `A = 103x159`. It works in the case of `2` but it fails if want to reduce it `4` times. Any ideas?

Comment: @emax I'm having difficulty understanding your requirements. Do you want some kind of generalization like summing over all `a x b` submatrices? Maybe you should expand your question with some background for your question

Comment: ...and since 103 is [prime](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=103&dataset=), you cannot divide that matrix into equally sized submatrices. Or do you actually want to perform [image processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)), i.e. convolve with a weighting matrix such as a [box blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur)?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I tried to explain my problem better

Comment: @emax Yes, that basically looks like what a blur filter would achieve. You may want to check out `opencv`. Or `pandas`. Though you can also replace the `2`s in my source by other factors (except for the `+2` parts) for a quick try. And comment out the `assert`ions.

Answer (score 1):

I see that there is a solution using `numpy.maxtrix`, maybe you can test my solution too and return your feedbacks.

It works with `a*b` matrix if `a and b are even`. Otherwise, it may fail if `a or b are odd`.

Here is my solution:

```
v = [
        [3,4,5,6],
        [2,3,4,5],
        [2,2,0,1],
        [5,2,2,3]
    ]

def shape(v):
    return len(v), len(v[0])

def chunks(v, step):
    """
    Chunk list step per step and sum
    Example: step = 2 
    [3,4,5,6] => [7,11]
    [2,3,4,5] => [5,9]
    [2,2,0,1] => [4,1]
    [5,2,2,3] => [7,5]
    """
    for i in v:
        for k in range(0, len(i),step):
            yield sum(j for j in i[k:k+step])

def sum_chunks(k, step):
    """
    Sum near values with step
    Example: step = 2
    [                   
        [7,11],         [   
        [5,9],      =>      [12, 11],
        [4,1],              [20, 6]
        [7,5]           ]
    ]
    """
    a, c = [k[i::step] for i in range(step)], []
    print(a)
    for m in a:
        # sum near values
        c.append([sum(m[j:j+2]) for j in range(0, len(m), 2)])  
    return c

rows, columns = shape(v)
chunk_list = list(chunks(v, columns // 2))
final_sum = sum_chunks(chunk_list, rows // 2)

print(final_sum)
```

Output:

```
[[12, 11], [20, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't saw that answer before. Yes we've done, maybe, the same approach.